# Purging old versions of Multimedia Components

Tags: core-service, purgetool

When I purge old versions of Multimedia Components, does Tridion also remove the binary content from the Database of the old versions?  [Here is the documentation for the PowerShell version](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dpurge&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1435306887586&currentQuery=purge&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-D51E5BE8-1ADC-4089-BABF-CAF0FA6A70E1&query=&scope=&filename=GUID-D51E5BE8-1ADC-4089-BABF-CAF0FA6A70E1.xml&docid=GUID-D51E5BE8-1ADC-4089-BABF-CAF0FA6A70E1&inner_id=&tid=&addHistory=true&resource=&toc=false).  I am using this Core Service client code:

```
PurgeOldVersionsInstructionData purgeIntructions = new PurgeOldVersionsInstructionData();
purgeIntructions.VersionsToKeep = 1;
purgeIntructions.Recursive = false;
List<LinkToIdentifiableObjectData> itemsToPurge = new List<LinkToIdentifiableObjectData>();
folderLink.IdRef = "tcm:123-2-2";
itemsToPurge.Add(folderLink);
purgeIntructions.Containers = itemsToPurge.ToArray();
int versionsCleaned = client.PurgeOldVersions(purgeIntructions);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does. Note that binary content can be "shared" between versions. Binary content is automatically removed if all versions referring to it are deleted/purged.